# Why does this regex expression give two different results in Python and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, substring

I have the following string:

> [?]The Taliban Have Gone High-Tech. That Poses a Dilemma for the U.S. The frequency and ferocity of the nighttime Taliban attacks are linked to attempts by Afghan forces, based in small checkpoints across the country, to hold territory that has been wrested away from the militants. Afghan troops said the missing devices were reported as "Battle losses," but could not support that claim with any proof or records to explain where or when they were left behind, according to the documents. Over the summer and fall, the Afghan National Army suffered 15 percent fewer casualties around Kandahar than it had during the same period in 2016.The documents credited the night-vision equipment for the marked reduction, concluding that the devices are "Becoming an integral part of base defense plans." The American military is now planning to equip the unit with roughly 2,500 night-vision goggles as part of what the documents described as a concept for a "Permanent program." Capt. Tom Gresback, a spokesman for United States forces in Afghanistan, declined to comment on the plans to distribute the devices to the Afghan National Army, as outlined in the military documents. With the night-vision devices, Taliban fighters have been able to approach Afghan bases nearly undetected before attacking. Zabihullah Mujahid, a spokesman for the Taliban, said fighters obtained night-vision devices after attacking Afghan bases or capturing members of the Afghan security forces. In Helmand Province, Marine Corps advisers are helping a request by the 505th Zone of the Afghan National Police to receive night-vision devices, Col.Reduced

And, I want to get the following output (Removing "[?]" and "Reduced"):

> The Taliban Have Gone High-Tech. That Poses a Dilemma for the U.S. The frequency and ferocity of the nighttime Taliban attacks are linked to attempts by Afghan forces, based in small checkpoints across the country, to hold territory that has been wrested away from the militants. Afghan troops said the missing devices were reported as "Battle losses," but could not support that claim with any proof or records to explain where or when they were left behind, according to the documents. Over the summer and fall, the Afghan National Army suffered 15 percent fewer casualties around Kandahar than it had during the same period in 2016.The documents credited the night-vision equipment for the marked reduction, concluding that the devices are "Becoming an integral part of base defense plans." The American military is now planning to equip the unit with roughly 2,500 night-vision goggles as part of what the documents described as a concept for a "Permanent program." Capt. Tom Gresback, a spokesman for United States forces in Afghanistan, declined to comment on the plans to distribute the devices to the Afghan National Army, as outlined in the military documents. With the night-vision devices, Taliban fighters have been able to approach Afghan bases nearly undetected before attacking. Zabihullah Mujahid, a spokesman for the Taliban, said fighters obtained night-vision devices after attacking Afghan bases or capturing members of the Afghan security forces. In Helmand Province, Marine Corps advisers are helping a request by the 505th Zone of the Afghan National Police to receive night-vision devices, Col.

On python, the following regex successfully strips out "[?]" and "Reduced": `'\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced'`. However, on Javascript that same regex returns:

> ?]The Taliban Have Gone High-Tech. That Poses a Dilemma for the U.S. The frequency and ferocity of the nighttime Taliban attacks are linked to attempts by Afghan forces, based in small checkpoints across the country, to hold territory that has been wrested away from the militants. Afghan troops said the missing devices were reported as "Battle losses," but could not support that claim with any proof or records to explain where or when they were left behind, according to the documents. Over the summer and fall, the Afghan National Army suffered 15 percent fewer casualties around Kandahar than it had during the same period in 2016.The documents credited the night-vision equipment for the marked reduction, concluding that the devices are "Becoming an integral part of base defense plans." The American military is now planning to equip the unit with roughly 2,500 night-vision goggles as part of what the documents described as a concept for a "Permanent program." Capt. Tom Gresback, a spokesman for United States forces in Afghanistan, declined to comment on the plans to distribute the devices to the Afghan National Army, as outlined in the military documents. With the night-vision devices, Taliban fighters have been able to approach Afghan bases nearly undetected before attacking. Zabihullah Mujahid, a spokesman for the Taliban, said fighters obtained night-vision devices after attacking Afghan bases or capturing members of the Afghan security forces. In Helmand Province, Marine Corps advisers are helping a request by the 505th Zone of the Afghan National Police to receive night-vision devices, Col.Reduced,]The Taliban Have Gone High-Tech. That Poses a Dilemma for the U.S. The frequency and ferocity of the nighttime Taliban attacks are linked to attempts by Afghan forces, based in small checkpoints across the country, to hold territory that has been wrested away from the militants. Afghan troops said the missing devices were reported as "Battle losses," but could not support that claim with any proof or records to explain where or when they were left behind, according to the documents. Over the summer and fall, the Afghan National Army suffered 15 percent fewer casualties around Kandahar than it had during the same period in 2016.The documents credited the night-vision equipment for the marked reduction, concluding that the devices are "Becoming an integral part of base defense plans." The American military is now planning to equip the unit with roughly 2,500 night-vision goggles as part of what the documents described as a concept for a "Permanent program." Capt. Tom Gresback, a spokesman for United States forces in Afghanistan, declined to comment on the plans to distribute the devices to the Afghan National Army, as outlined in the military documents. With the night-vision devices, Taliban fighters have been able to approach Afghan bases nearly undetected before attacking. Zabihullah Mujahid, a spokesman for the Taliban, said fighters obtained night-vision devices after attacking Afghan bases or capturing members of the Afghan security forces. In Helmand Province, Marine Corps advisers are helping a request by the 505th Zone of the Afghan National Police to receive night-vision devices, Col.

(It fails to fully strip out [?]).

I tested the regex on python, and it worked as expected: https://regex101.com/r/T16EcU/1/

However, as expected, when I tested it with Javascript, it failed to strip out the [?]: https://regex101.com/r/XKtn7s/1

How do I modify the regex expression so it works on javascript?

It also worth noting that sometimes the initial string will have a space after the [?] instead of directly having the word "The" after [?].

Here is my Javascript code:

```
//"documentBodyText.match" equals the sample string I gave in the post
const summary = documentBodyText.match('\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced');
console.log(summary);
```

Here is my python code:

```
//summary_page_text equals the sample string I gave in the post
target_quote_object = re.search('\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced', summary_page_text)
target_quote_text = target_quote_object.group(1)
print(target_quote_text)
```

Comment: `documentBodyText.match(/\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced/)[1]`

Comment: [***TL;DR***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR) Please read: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do you really need to *full* text to show the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I'll marked it solved tomorrow, I'm busy finishing something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.match("\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced")`, the regex is built with the constructor notation, and  the single backslashes are lost, thus your regex is actually `[?]s*(.*?)Reduced`, and it matches a literal `?`, then zero or more `s`  chars, and then captures any 0+ chars up to the first `Reduced`. Not what you want.

You need to define the regex with a regex literal, and access group 1 the same way as in Python:

```
var m = s.match(/\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced/); // Get the match
if (m)                                   // If there was a match
    console.log(m[1])                    // Grab what is in Group 1
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var s ='[?]The Taliban Have Gone High-Tech. That Poses a Dilemma for the U.S. The frequency and ferocity of the nighttime Taliban attacks are linked to attempts by Afghan forces, based in small checkpoints across the country, to hold territory that has been wrested away from the militants. Afghan troops said the missing devices were reported as "Battle losses," but could not support that claim with any proof or records to explain where or when they were left behind, according to the documents. Over the summer and fall, the Afghan National Army suffered 15 percent fewer casualties around Kandahar than it had during the same period in 2016.The documents credited the night-vision equipment for the marked reduction, concluding that the devices are "Becoming an integral part of base defense plans." The American military is now planning to equip the unit with roughly 2,500 night-vision goggles as part of what the documents described as a concept for a "Permanent program." Capt. Tom Gresback, a spokesman for United States forces in Afghanistan, declined to comment on the plans to distribute the devices to the Afghan National Army, as outlined in the military documents. With the night-vision devices, Taliban fighters have been able to approach Afghan bases nearly undetected before attacking. Zabihullah Mujahid, a spokesman for the Taliban, said fighters obtained night-vision devices after attacking Afghan bases or capturing members of the Afghan security forces. In Helmand Province, Marine Corps advisers are helping a request by the 505th Zone of the Afghan National Police to receive night-vision devices, Col.Reduced';
var m = s.match(/\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced/);
if (m)
 console.log(m[1])
```